# Wrong App icon in iOS multitask view for iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, multitasking, viewswitcher

Our iOS App gives the users “Tenants” the option to change the app icon right from within the app, by entering their ID. Since with iOS 10.3 Apple finally gave developers the ability to change their app’s icon programmatically by using “setAlternateIconName”,  there is a strange behavior in which wrong app icon is appeared in multitasking app switcher after dynamically change the app icon using "setAlternateIconName"; this only happens with iOS 13 and the correct app icon shows again after restart the device.  Steps:

1. install our app and enter the tenantID in the which decide the tenant icon and change the icon using the "setAlternateIconName" from default icon to Icon A
2. The app icon itself is changed and the app icon in the multitasking app switcher is changed.
3. Delete the app.
4. Reinstall the app again and enter another tenantID to change to different icon from default icon to Icon B
5. The app icon itself is changed to Icon B but in the multitasking app switcher is still shows the Icon A. ?!

[default app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBGMh.jpg)

[change the app icon to icon A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSeuK.jpg)

[change the app icon to icon B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDFp.jpg)

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

Uninstall App → Restart Device → Install App

It worked for me!

Comment: I think just restart is enough.